# FreeRADIUS Server installation issue on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I am observing the following issue while installing FreeRADIUS Server v2.2.5

```
configure: error: in `/root/freeradius-server-2.2.5':
configure: error: failed locating OpenSSL headers
See `config.log' for more details
root@ip-ent-fvt-psi1:~/freeradius-server-2.2.5#
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the OpenSSL development headers.

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`